# How to split a movie with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to write a program to split a movie with a selected length. Following is my code.

```
movieFullFileName = '001.mp4';
videoObject = VideoReader(movieFullFileName);

% Determine how many frames there are.
numberOfFrames = videoObject.NumberOfFrames;
vidHeight = videoObject.Height;
vidWidth = videoObject.Width;

% Create a VideoWriter object to write the video out to a new, different file.
writerObj = VideoWriter('new001.mp4', 'MPEG-4');
open(writerObj);

for frame = 1 : 1000
    % Extract the frame from the movie structure.
    thisFrame = read(videoObject, frame);

    writeVideo(writerObj, thisFrame);
end

close(writerObj);
```

The problem is that it will reformat the movie but what I want is just split the movie and then output it directly. How to do it with Matlab?

Comment: What did you mean by 'reformat' exactly?

Comment: For example, I have a movie with 100MB, I want to split it into two parts, so I should get two file with around 50MB for each one, but the output from the above code is much bigger than 50MB, which means the format is different and I don't want that.

Comment: Check the properties of the videoObject and writerObj. You can see that they are different. I think problem may be there.

Comment: You're re-encoding the data so you should expect the output to be larger, unless you add more compression. If the original file wasn't created in Matlab, it's also possible that it's encoded in a different manner from the basic options available to `VideoWriter`. If you want to actually "split" the file, you should use real video editing tools that support a "pass through" option for MPEG-4 encoding (ffmepg and QuickTime Pro have this, but I don't think Matlab does). This will leave the original data mostly untouched and just adjust the headers.

Comment: thanks @horchler I used ffmepg to do this task